# Solve Algebra Equations in bulk

Tags: windows, math

I need a program that will solve a bunch of algebra equations from a list and output all the answers ex:

```
1+1
2+2
```

out:

```
2
4
```

I am using windows 7

Answer (score 1):

First point - your example is not algebra nor equations - it is arithmetical operations. The difference algebra: `x + 3 = 5 => x=?` while arithmetic `4 + 4 = ?`

Assuming that your file really is a set of lines like your in example, i.e. simple arithmetic statements with spaces between and **no** other spaces:

1. install [python](https://www.python.org/) for [windows](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2.exe), **it is free,** accepting the option to add it to the path
2. Open a command prompt and `cd` to the directory as your file is in
3. type `python`
4. type:

```
for line in open('sums.txt'):
       for item in line.split(' '):
           if len(item) > 1:
               print(item, '=', eval(item))

exit
```

The above assumes that you called your list `sums.txt` and will print out your results. With a little bit of reading you can set up a script to do this for you and add the use of trigonometric functions such as sin, cos, tan, etc. Note that basic the operators you can have in your text file, *with python3*, are:

- Add: `+`
- Subtract: `-`
- Multiply: `*`
- Divide: `\`
- Floor: `\\`
- Modulo: `%`
- Brackets: `()`

Comment: It was just an example I have algebra but can you close this because I don't need it anymore.